# Anylogic: multi environment simulation

Tags: gis, simulation, anylogic

I need to simulate a wide range business activities, including a rail network and some stations inside it.
The Problem is that I need a global scope of the network using the GIS Map, and data analysis is needed in this scope. Meanwhile I need microscopic analysis of some stations to evaluate how each station rail yard is working.

Is it possible to handle both of these models in a single Anylogic file? because these two are related to each other. and if not how can it be handled?

Update:
I created a new agent for my rail network environment and developed a simple rail flowchart but when the first train is going to be injected from trainSource the following error is displayed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.<population>[1]:

This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Continuous' and can't have behaviour for space 'Continuous, based on GIS map'
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this error?

Comment: Which question do you want answered? Please only ask 1 question per issue :) --> Some tips for writing good SOF questions: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, the second question is actually when I have encountered a problem in my own method of solving the issue. I don't know whether the method is good so I kept the original question too. forgive me for this.:)

Comment: Hey, no worries. Best split it into 2 issues (with good descriptive titles), though. This helps future users with similar issues searching for the right answer :) Happy to help :)